# How to inform a variable with a random value in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-2.0

I have a client list in Django, and I need to return a random number between 1 and 999 for each new client.

Also, for each new client and random number generated, I need to inform whether or not the client is approved to receive a certain amount of credit. And, if approved, there are some conditions as well.

I need this for a job interview as a Junior dev, who's gonna be working with Django RESTFramework and, in the future, a little bit of React as well.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
income = float()
score = random.randint(1, 999)
aprovado = False
credit = float()

if 0 < score < 300:
    aprovado = False
elif 299 < score < 600:
    aprovado = True
    credit = 1000
elif 599 < score < 800:
    aprovado = True
    if income < 2000:
        credit = 1000
    else:
        credit = income * 0.5
elif 799 < score < 951:
    aprovado = True
    credit = income * 2
else:
    aprovado = True
    credit = 1000000
```

The logic is working properly in a separate (blank) file, but I cannot find a way to insert this to the Django app.

The 'score' needs to be random for each client, and it must also be a non-editable field, but it must be visible.

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Do determine this some idea of project structure is needed. What are the internal apps so we can determine which app is most appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django projects are comprised of a collection of apps, each one charged with handling a certain aspect of the project. Django has a somewhat standard set of files within each of these apps. For example in the trivial example of a ToDo project, you may find these apps:

ToDo project:

- Users: for any functionality extending the django user model or generally outside of the scope of the django user system
- Alerts: for alerting users of todos
- ToDos: the actual ToDo app
- ...

Within anyone of these apps you will usually find these files:

1. models
2. urls
3. admin
4. apps
5. serializers (django rest projects)
6. tasks (celery projects)
7. views
8. managers (if you create custom managers for your models)
9. tests

To know where that functionality goes you have to know what the workflow is. Is this something that happens upon user registration? Is there an app that handles user registration? If those are both yes, then put it wherever user registration logic happens in that app. Perhaps this happens in the User serializer, view/viewset or User model itself...

These links may help:

- [Blog post about django app structure](https://djangobook.com/mdj2-django-structure/)
- [Blog post listed on hacker news about django project structure](https://www.jamesbeith.co.uk/blog/how-to-structure-django-projects/)
- [And of course the django docs](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/)